# If formula or other formula to get a blank cell

Tags: arrays, count, countif, sumifs, ifs

I am using if formula or any other formula and getting some results with zero. How to get those cells blank when it contains zero. I am writing below formula:

=Arrayformula(B9:B*22)

Couln't try anything as all comes with zero or error.